# Exclude database from django migrations

Tags: django, sphinx, django-migrations

Is there a way to exclude database from django migrations?

I have a sphinxsearch database in my django project:

```
DATABASES['sphinxsearch'] = {
    'ENGINE': 'sphinxsearch.backend.sphinx',
    ...
}
```

And when I try to run manage.py makemigrations command, Django tries to run
`SHOW FULL TABLES` query against it

which leads to an error, because this is wrong syntax for sphinxql

```
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\introspection.py", line 56, in get_table_list
    cursor.execute("SHOW FULL TABLES")
...
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting VARIABLES near 'FULL TABLES'")
```

Comment: Try creating a database router and return `False` for [`allow_migrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/multi-db/#allow_migrate)

Answer (score 0):

An exception to this rule is the makemigrations command.

It validates the migration history in the databases to catch problems with the existing migration files (which could be caused by editing them) before creating new migrations.

By default, it checks only the default database, but it consults the `allow_migrate()` method of routers if any are installed.

`makemigrations` always creates migrations for model changes, but if `allow_migrate()` returns `False`, any migration operations for the model_name will be silently skipped when running migrate on the db.

Changing the behavior of `allow_migrate()` for models that already have migrations may result in broken foreign keys, extra tables, or missing tables. When `makemigrations` verifies the migration history, it skips databases where no app is allowed to `migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class DBMigrateRouter(object):
"""
A router to control all database operations on models in the
auth application.
"""

def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
    """
    Allows migration for default DB 
    """
    return db == 'default'
```

Add this class to settings file

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['path.to.DBMigrateRouter']
```

This will skip migrations on databases other than "default".